# How to import text file with delimited white spaces to datagrid or datatable?

Tags: c#, datagrid

What about this: it has a delimited whitespaces and all I want to happen is to import this in database or datatable with their headers..

I'm having a hard time because the original file has no fixed spaces and other samples separated by semicolon but this is different.

Is there a way to import this to the data table that assigned those fields to its specific column header. Pls guide me. First time to encounter this.
[here's the sample text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6lH0.png)

Comment: Can you post the code you've written so far?

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of your sample file (original) it seems that you can treat it as space delimited data, with the exception that the date time has a space within the value. So if you use a streamreader with ReadLine() for each row you can use     List columns = text.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries). You can then allocate each column's value according to the header row remembering to append the time part to the date.